# Swap kth position from start and end in a single traverse linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have come across the following implementation for swapping the kth position from start and end in a linked list in single traverse.

```
node *list;
node *p, *q, *r;
p = q = r = list;

i = 1;

while(p != NULL)
{
    if(i != k)
    {
        q = q->next;
        i++;
    }//q will eventually point to kth node from starting

    if(i == k)
    {
        r = r->next
    }//r will eventually point to kth node from end

    p = p->next;

}

 Swap q & r elements
```

But I feel it's not the right implementation, could anyone look at it and verify if it's correct?

If it's wrong, what changes would I have to make?

Comment: Do you know the size of the list upfront?

Comment: Please test code yourself rather than asking whether it works on [so]. Neither feelings nor [so] make good replacements for your compiler.

Comment: Yes @arunmoezhi I know the size upfront.

Comment: If it is a doubly linked list you can traverse in both the directions to find the Kth elements and then exchange their values

Comment: For singly linked list of size N, find the Kth element and then N-K+1 th element and exchange their values

Comment: Within limits, it is correct.  The immediate problem will be that you need the pointers to the elements before the ones you swap so you can adjust the pointers pointing at the elements to be swapped.  That's easily taken care of.  Obviously, if there aren't `k` entries in the list, then there's nothing to swap.

Answer (score 1):

This question is majorly associated with finding right nodes and respective previous node. 
Then essentially there are 2 cases when nodes are starting and ending node or they are intermediate nodes.

First adjust previous pointer to point swap targets and then swap next pointers of targets. That is all ... following is complete java code for reference ->

**JAVA Code**

```
public class SwapKthNodeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test10Node();
        System.out.println();
        Test2Node();
    }

    private static void Test2Node() {
        Node head = Node.getNodeListHead(2);
        Node.ToString(head);
        int k = 1;
        head = Node.SwapKthNodeFromStartNEnd(head, k);
        Node.ToString(head);
        k = 2;
        head = Node.SwapKthNodeFromStartNEnd(head, k);
        Node.ToString(head);
    }

    public static void Test10Node(){
        Node head = Node.getNodeListHead(10);
        Node.ToString(head);
        int k = 2;
        head = Node.SwapKthNodeFromStartNEnd(head, k);
        Node.ToString(head);
        k=1;
        head = Node.SwapKthNodeFromStartNEnd(head, k);
        Node.ToString(head);
        k=3;
        head = Node.SwapKthNodeFromStartNEnd(head, k);
        Node.ToString(head);
        k=4;
        head = Node.SwapKthNodeFromStartNEnd(head, k);
        Node.ToString(head);
        k=5;
        head = Node.SwapKthNodeFromStartNEnd(head, k);
        Node.ToString(head);

    }

}

class Node {
    int val;
    Node next;
    Node(int val, Node next) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next= next;
    }
    public static int length(Node head){
        Node trav = head;
        int count = 0;
        while(trav != null){
            count++;
            trav = trav.next;
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static void ToString(Node head) {
        // just print the list which we created
        Node trav = head;
        while(trav != null){
            System.out.print(trav.val+" ");
            trav = trav.next;
        }
    }

    public static Node SwapKthNodeFromStartNEnd(Node head, int k) {
        System.out.println();

        int len = Node.length(head);
        if( k > len)    return head;

        // would be the same thing just making it reverse
        // to make process more cleaner
        if( k == len)   k = 1;

        Node x = head, y = head, t = head;
        Node xp = null, yp = null;
        int i = 1;

        while (i++ < k) {
            xp = x;
            x  = x.next;
            t  = t.next;
        }

        while(t.next != null){
            yp = y;
            y  = y.next;
            t  = t.next;
        }

//      System.out.println("x= "+x.val+" y= "+ y.val);
//      if(xp != null)  System.out.println("xp= "+xp.val);
//      if(yp != null)  System.out.println("yp= "+yp.val);

        // first adjust previous pointer of two nodes
        // later swap the next pointers of both nodes

        // CASE-1: case nodes have previous pointer
        // and they are not start and end node 
        if(xp != null && yp != null ){
            xp.next = y;
            yp.next = x;
        }
        // CASE-2: x and y nodes are first and last
        // this case xp is null
        else if (xp == null && yp != null){
            head    = y;
            yp.next = x;
        }

        t      = y.next;
        y.next = x.next;
        x.next = t;

        return head;
    }


    public static Node getNodeListHead(int nodes){
        int idx = nodes-1;
        Node head = new Node(nodes, null);
        while(idx >= 1){
            head = new Node(idx, head);
            idx--;
        }


        return head;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to geeks4geeks for all boundary cases:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-kth-node-from-beginning-with-kth-node-from-end-in-a-linked-list/

Comment: please make your answer self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

For singly linked list of size N, find the `K`th element and then `N-K+1` th element and exchange their values
And as Jonathan said, you have to take care of special cases and keep track of additional pointers to do the swap. But the crux is you have to swap the `K`th element with the `N-K+1`th element